# 100% packet loss when pinging Raspberry Pi running web server

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi

I set up a web server on a Raspberry Pi (running a Debian package) and everything that I need is set up, and I've uploaded my website via FileZilla. Now I can connect to the server via the static IP address within my local network, but when testing it via just ping, I get the message "Packet lost (100%)".

I've done some research and tried a full power cycle on my router, and I still get this message. I am fairly new to web hosting and don't know much about it,  but how do I get rid of this 100% packet loss?

I've set up my Domain name with dot.tk and the domain (if you want to test it) is `http://www.miworldmc.tk` . I've set it up with the DNS so that it points to my IP address.

And also, I asked a question on Yahoo Answers and I was told to port forward my local IP and use TCP/80. Is this the right configuration? Is this why I'm getting 100% packet loss?

If not, someone please tell me what to do! Thankyou so much if you help!

Comment: Are you saying that everything works from your local network, but it doesn't work when you try to access your Pi remotely over the Internet?

Comment: Yes, well, not really, I don't know how to test it remotely over the internet. If i enter the domain, it takes me to my router page.

Comment: If you're taken to your router page, you still need to set up port forwarding from your router to your Raspberry Pi device.

Comment: I managed to test it via Nibbler and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie  - If you are getting the configuration page, then the router is NOT configured the correct way, to forward the packets to your `Raspberry Pi`

Comment: It works as far as i can tell, it's just when i enter the domain name, it gives me my router page, but when i enter the Raspberry Pi's Static IP Address, it works fine. I have tested it on Nibbler, and it is being processed ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping is an ICMP echo request. This is blocked by firewalls by default. It's likely the firewall in Debian or your router is set to block ICMP echo requests. You can test which by doing tracert from a windows box using CMD, to the IP or name you are pinging. The response will stop at the device causing the problem. You can also use traceroute from the command line of a linux box.

Ping does not travel on port 80, that is reserved for HTTP traffic.

Comment: Cheers, this is not affecting my website is it? Can it still be accessed or do i have to enable ICMP echo requests?